# How to handle 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I'm facing this issue on my code that was working until a couple of days ago but from today is stopped working.
The issue is related to the combinations task from itertools as follow:

```
from itertools import combinations


def combinations(items):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, len(items) + 1):
        result.extend(itertools.combinations(items, i)) 
    page_text = page_text.css('.rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_LhsContainerInner')

    for match in page_text:
        teams = match.css('.rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetailsTeam_TeamName ::text').getall()
        times = match.css('.rcl-ParticipantFixtureDetails_BookCloses ::text').getall()
        row = {
            "Home": teams[0], 
            "Away": teams[1],
            "Time": times
        }
        rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
data = []
for i, (home, away, time) in enumerate(df[['Home', 'Away', 'Time']].values):
    home_words, away_words = home.split(), away.split()
    for home_combo in combinations(home_words):
        for away_combo in combinations(away_words):
            if home_combo and away_combo:
                data.append([i, home, away, time, f'{" ".join(home_combo)} - {" ".join(away_combo)}'])
```

this is the error

```
     97 for i, (home, away, time) in enumerate(df[['Home', 'Away', 'Time']].values):
     98     home_words, away_words = home.split(), away.split()
---> 99     for home_combo in combinations(home_words):
    100         for away_combo in combinations(away_words):
    101             if home_combo and away_combo:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
from itertools import combinations

def combinations(items):
    ...
```

Your `combinations` function masks the `combinations` you import from `itertools`, so you're just calling your own function, which implicitly returns `None`.  Just rename your function to something else and you'll be able to reference the desired imported function.

Comment: Also probably a good idea to have the function return something.

Comment: @pavel Yes, if the user-defined function is in fact supposed to return something.

Comment: Thank for your reply. You mean I have to change "combinations" on both after def and in the loop (where is the error located) or only at the beginning of the code?

Comment: Where it should be located the return element? How should I set it up?

Comment: @Carolino The posted code has the following:  (1) `from itertools import combinations`  (2) `def combinations(items)`  (3) `itertools.combinations`.  As posted, this won't even run, since you don't import `itertools`, so `itertools.combinations` will be unresolved.  If you want it to stay that way, then change the import to `import itertools`.  That will avoid the name conflict.  But if you want to just import `combinations` directly into your namespace, then the called function name needs to be `combinations`, and you need to rename your own definition of `combinations` to avoid the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function in the for loop that isn't returning anything as of now. You can add a return statement to your function and pass that to your loop. Remember, the value returned by the function should be an iterable like list, tuples, dictionary, dictionary etc.

Comment: Where it should be located the return element? How should I set it up?

Comment: Return statement should be the last statement in your function (i.e, combinations). In your case, you can return the variable(should be an iterable) that you want to loop on.